# nginx https without www doesnt redirect to https www

Tags: nginx

redirect from http www and http non www all redirects to https www but if i try to redirect from https non www to https www. it doesnt work. here are my server blocks

```
server {


                listen 443 ssl;
                 # catch all non-www domains
                server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$  ~(?<domain>.+)$;
                #return 301 https://www.$domain$request_uri;
                if ($host = $server_name) {
                        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
                }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$  ~(?<domain>.+)$;
        return 301 https://www.$domain$request_uri;
        }


}
```

whats buggy in my code?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using regex in the `server_name`?

Answer (score 0):

that's all

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # ssl stuff, like ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key

    server_name domain.tld;
    return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # ssl stuff, like ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key

    server_name www.domain.tld;

    location / {
        # usual stuff here
    }
}
```